# Swift UIlabels not showing properly in uistackview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilabel

I am trying to programatically add uilabels into a stackview but for some reason it is not showing up properly. Here is what I have:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.textColor = UIColor.black
label.text = "Text that goes before "
    
let matlabel = MTMathUILabel()
matlabel.labelMode = MTMathUILabelMode.text
matlabel.latex = "$\\frac{x}{y}$"
matlabel.textColor = UIColor.black
   
let endLabel = UILabel()
label.textColor = UIColor.black
label.text = "? after"

self.textStack.addArrangedSubview(label)
self.textStack.addArrangedSubview(matlabel)      
self.textStack.addArrangedSubview(endLabel)
```

And here is what I get
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a "endLabel" but you didn't set text on it. You mistakenly set text on "label" so it just override your "label" text. try the following code:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.textColor = UIColor.black
label.text = "Text that goes before "

let matlabel = MTMathUILabel()
matlabel.labelMode = MTMathUILabelMode.text
matlabel.latex = "$\\frac{x}{y}$"
matlabel.textColor = UIColor.black

let endLabel = UILabel()
endLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
endLabel.text = "? after"

self.textStack.addArrangedSubview(label)
self.textStack.addArrangedSubview(matlabel)      
self.textStack.addArrangedSubview(endLabel)
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been at this for so long I can't believe i missed that

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think what you wanted to really do was:

```
self.textStack.addArrangedSubview(label)
self.textStack.addArrangedSubview(matlabel)   
self.textStack.addArrangedSubview(endLabel)
```

But, to your point, the "label" is not appearing. Have you tried setting the alignment and distribution?